# Xml for custom Button

Tags: android, android-widget

I have many custom buttons in my layout xml. And each of that button has property i.e width.
Can I create one xml for that custom button with defines width property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dimens resource and referance that from your button

xml resources file:

```
<resources>
<dimen name="my_dimen">10dip</dimen> </resources>
```

xml layout file:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="@dimen/my_dimen"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Attribute Resources` for your custom views(for example buttons).create a new file in your project "res/values" folder by selecting it and choosing "File", "New", "File". Enter "attrs.xml" as the file.Then declare-styleable for your view.Now you can use them in XML layout when add your view to layout.You can see more details [here](http://hub.tutsplus.com/categories/development/tutorials/mobile-14548-android-sdk-creating-custom-views).